# Uploading Picture Is Corrupted

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to allow users to upload a new profile pic by clicking on the old one.

I am using ajax and a file reader to do so

```
$('#profileImage').click(function(){ $('#image-file').trigger('click'); });

                $('#image-file').on('change',function(){
                    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

                        var FR= new FileReader();

                        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);                    
                        FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
                          document.getElementById("profileImage").src = e.target.result;

                          imgData = e.target.result;

                          var formData = {
                            'name'              : localStorage.getItem('email'),
                            'image'             : imgData
                          };

                            console.log("image data: " + imgData);


                            $.ajax({
                                 type   : 'POST',
                                 url    : '/uploadprofile.php',
                                 data   : formData,
                                 dataType: 'text',
                                 encode : true
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                            });


                        });
                    }





                });
```

The new image is loaded onto the old picture and the console tracks the image data sent through.
The only issue is that the newly updated picture is not visible to the container. It shows an icon of a broken picture.
This is my php file that handles the insertion

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);


    if ($json == "") {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
    } else {
        $name = $json["name"]; //within square bracket should be same as Utils.imageName & Utils.image

        $image = $json["image"];
    }




    $response = array();

    $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");

    //unlink old picture
    // unlink($name.".jpg");
    $oldName = $name;
    $name .= date("D M d Y G:i");
    $name = str_replace(' ', '', $name);

    $fullPath = "http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/".$name.".jpg";

    $return = file_put_contents("uploads/".$name.".jpg", $decodedImage);

    if($return !== false){
        $response['email'] = $oldName;
        $response['image'] = $image;
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        $sql = "UPDATE Users SET PicLocation = '$fullPath' WHERE Email = '$oldName'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }else{
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = "Image Uploaded Failed";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

The value for $response['image'] that gets printed out is correct but it doesn't seem to show the picture. The data is corrupted somehow. Is there something I should do to get the correct data?
Additionally, sometimes I get the error:

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://tanglecollege.com/uploadprofile.php 406 (Not Acceptable)

I don't know what it means and there doesn't seem to be a good explanation.

Also, the file that gets saved to the server is corrupted in some way. I can track the base64 data being passed along from js to php but when it is saved as a file, that file is corrupted and the image can not be read from the filepath.

Comment: "The value for $response['image'] that gets printed out is correct but it doesn't seem to show the picture."... you're only printing it in the console. Not sure why you'd expect it to show an image there? And anyway as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) the dataURL is base64-encoded. It's just text. If you insert it into an `<img` tag the tag should be able to read it. You seem to have done that earlier in your code...or is that the thing you're saying isn't working? It's not quite clear.

Comment: The file that gets saved to the server is corrupted in some way. I can track the base64 data being passed along from js to php but when it is saved as a file, that file is corrupted and the image can not be read from the filepath.

Comment: Ok. That's not how you explained it at all. Can you give a sample of what `$image` contains in the PHP. Then we can see if it's really a decodable string or not

Comment: image data: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4TgsRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADAALAAIAAAAmAAAIqgEPAAIAAAAGAAAI0AEQAAIAAAAKAAAI1gESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAI4AEbAAUAAAABAAAI6AEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAmAAAI8AEyAAIAAAAUAAAJFgITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAJKuocAAcAAAgMAAAAngAAFuYc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: Are you quite sure? Because that doesn't look like a valid base64 string to me. And PHP agrees. If you execute base64_encode on that string with strict mode on then (as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)) it returns `false` because the string is not a valid base64 string. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8db78ef1c8930f28337fd0f2734ef495bd49398b . If it's not valid, that would explain your problem though.

Comment: even if you strip the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part from the string (as suggested in various things I've read online) it still fails to decode correctly.